# FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever IllegalArgumentException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to retrieve a image from a frame of a video using [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](http://wseemann.github.io/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/)

this is the code im using:
the variable path has this value: 
 "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/avnohellodev/videos/9e867aba83197862e7500ebe3ebfd68a.mp4"

```
final String path = msg.getUrl();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
                            mmr.setDataSource(path);
                            final Bitmap b = mmr.getFrameAtTime(2000000, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST); // frame at 2 seconds
                            mmr.release();

                            video_thumb.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    video_thumb.setImageBitmap(b);
                                }
                            });
                        }catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

when the code reaches the setDataSource i get

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFFF

Anything wrong with my code, or is this video not supported for some reason ?
I also don't mind a alternative to FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever if it works

Comment: its a string that has this value: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/avnohellodev/videos/9e867aba83197862e7500ebe3ebfd68a.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the prebuilt AAR's with HTTPS support found [here](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/blob/master/prebuilt-aars-with-https.zip?raw=true).

Comment: What do u mean by prebuilt AAR? How do we use them in our project and how do they solve the above issue? Could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: AAR's are packaged Android libraries. You import the AAR, add it as a dependency to your project and then you can use the library within your application. The is the alternative approach to adding the library to your applications build.gradle.

Comment: I did some research and found out :) , but thanks for ur reply. After adding the all-fmmr in the project I added the following in build.gradle file " compile project(':all-fmmr') " . However this was not able to resolve the crash.

Comment: Link not working, could you please provide more context